# Geolookup with Google Map, map not showing until browser resize

Tags: jquery-ui, dictionary

I have blank map on a page that is blank when the page is loaded. My web app has a facility for the subscriber to auto lookup an address using a geolookup plugin and then show the address on the map with a marker.

[image]

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Start typing address" class="form-control" name="location-input" id="location-input">
```

[image]

When I start typing in an address the lookup works as the possible address options drop down from the input. Now when I choose an address the google logo and the map controls appear on the map BUT the map with location marker does NOT. ONLY when I re size the browser does the map with location appears. I can then lookup another address and the map and marker works perfectly. So all in all, I need to do a browser re size to make the geolookup work.

Now I have look everywhere on the Internet and I have tried the recommended jquery window resize functions as below.. but does not work.

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.panTo(Marker1.getPosition());
```

});

[image]